# how to get next three business days by mysql (current data and next three days)

Tags: mysql

I want to get the three working days from the current date as excluding Saturday and Sunday. can any one help me out here.

I have tried the interval method and DayOfWeek(day) <> 1 AND DayOfWeek(day) <> 7 but it is not giving me the proper result

Comment: You want 3 dates returned? Tomorrow and the next two days that are not weeked, right?

Comment: yes exactely.
If today is friday then next three days would be monday , tuesday and wednesday

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but

```
select d
from
(
    select curdate() as d
    union all 
    select curdate() + interval 1 day
    union all 
    select curdate() + interval 2 day
    union all 
    select curdate() + interval 3 day
    union all 
    select curdate() + interval 4 day
) tmp
where dayofweek(d) not in (1,7)
order by d
limit 3
```

Comment: But i is not skipping the holidays if we encountered any holiday in between of the interval

Comment: Well, because you did not mention holidays in your question. Create a table with the holidays in your region and filter with that table.

Comment: Can we skip only saturday sunday at this stage

Comment: Yes, that is what my query does. Didn't you try it?

Comment: It is just ignoring as if we want an interval of 6 days it will show same as for four.
My requirement is it should catch next day id there is a holiday in the interval.
Mean if i select interval of 3 days from friday it shoud display upto wednesday not just ignore the saturday and sunday.
Let me explain a little as: i want 3 days date + interval 3 day
if there is saturday it should add monday if there is saturday and sunday it should add monday and tuesday.